# about jpa repository loop touch aop

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository, aop

```
@Autowired
OperateLogRepository operateLogRepository;

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.hm..repository..*(..))")
public void http() {
}

@Before("http()")
public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
}

@After("http()")
public void doAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
}

@Around("http()")
public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    if (operateLogRepository!=null) {
        List<OperateLog> operateLogList = operateLogRepository.findAll();
        OperateLog operateLog = new OperateLog();
        operateLog.setId("123");
        operateLogRepository.saveAndFlush(operateLog);
    }
    return pjp.proceed();
}
```

when saveAndFlush excute , loop aop ,but not insert data into db,i think that is saveAndFlush point, repeat touch aop

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? Why do you load all OperatorLog? What's important is that you exclude the OperatorLogRepository from this Aspect that causes the loop

Comment: Is `OperateLogRepository` somewhere in a `com.hm..repository` package? You omitted that crucial information by hiding the import statement. Furthermore, do you also want to intercept other method calls in `OperateLogRepository`? Otherwise you could simply exclude the class from aspect weaving. I can say more after you answer my questions or provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i want save all operateLog,  so i use aop , it is true , OperateLogRepository in  com.hm..repository

Comment: i use  spring jpa  and rest repository ,so i kill controller ,project only contain com.xx.entity and com.xx.repositroy

Comment: Thanks, but I do need more information. Please edit the question and extend the example code. Ideally, like I said, publish and MCVE, e.g. on GitHub. Seeing a partial aspect without the application it applies to, is not very insightful.